# Draw a barplot for dataframe with several columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe:

```
ID  Mean Min Max
A   10    4   18
B   20    6   22
C   12    2   78
```

I want to draw a bar plot with ID on x axis where on each ID there will be bars with mean min and max. How could i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this, editing the data:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  # data from wide to long format
  gather(variable, value, -ID) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ID, y = value, fill = reorder(variable, value))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

---

With data:

```
dat <- read.table(text =" ID  Mean Min Max
A   10    4   18
B   20    6   22
C   12    2   78", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ggplot, something like this will probably work:

```
g <- ggplot(DF,aes(x=ID,y=Mean))
g + geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Min, ymax=Max), width=.05)
```

Edited to remove an extra ending bracket

Comment: please correct your code. There is extra `)` at the end of it.